# read csv file in matlab with rows of different size

Tags: matlab, csv, import-from-csv, textscan

I'm going to read a big csv file in matlab which contains rows like this:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0
```

For reading big files I'm using `textscan` however I should define number of expected parameters in each line of text file.

Using `csvread` helps but it is too slow and seems to be not efficient.
Are there any methods to use `textscan` with uknown number of inputs in each line? or do you have any other suggestion for this situation?

Comment: For your example, what do you expect the created MATLAB variable to look like?  Will it be a numeric matrix (or perhaps logical matrix) with "short" rows padded with zeros?  Or a cell array with each row being in a separate element of the cell array?

Comment: @PhilGoddard Numerical matrix padded with zeros would be good. Cell array with one column which each cell contains a row would be good too.

Comment: Have you tried iterating yourself line by line, counting the commas (+ 1), so that you have the needed number of expected parameters - before the `textscan`? Maybe, it's faster than `csvread`!? And/Or, you really have no upper boundary for the amount of values per line, not even a silly one like 1000? Cleaning your (maybe too big initialized) array afterwards might also be faster!?

Comment: Please show your slow implementation of `csvread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said "*Numerical matrix padded with zeros would be good*", there is a solution using `textscan` which can give you that. The catch however is you have to know the maximum number of element a line can have (i.e. the longest line in your file).

Provided you know that, then a combination of the additional parameters for `textscan` allow you to read an incomplete line:

If you set the parameter `'EndOfLine','\r\n'`, the documentation explains:

> If there are missing values and an end-of-line sequence at the end of
>   the last line in a file, then textscan returns empty values for those
>   fields. This ensures that individual cells in output cell array, C,
>   are the same size.

So with the example data in your question saved as `differentRows.txt`, the following code:

```
% be sure about this, better to overestimate than underestimate
maxNumberOfElementPerLine = 10 ;

% build a reading format which can accomodate the longest line
readFormat = repmat('%f',1,maxNumberOfElementPerLine) ;

fidcsv = fopen('differentRows.txt','r') ;

M = textscan( fidcsv , readFormat , Inf ,...
    'delimiter',',',...
    'EndOfLine','\r\n',...
    'CollectOutput',true) ;

fclose(fidcsv) ;
M = cell2mat(M) ; % convert to numerical matrix
```

will return:

```
>> M
M =
     1     0     1     0     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1   NaN
     1     0     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     0     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     0     1     0     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0   NaN
```

---

As an alternative, if it makes a significant speed difference, you could import your data into integers instead of double. The trouble with that is `NaN` is not defined for integers, so you have 2 options:

- 1) Leave the *empty* entries to the default `0`

just replace the line which define the format specifier with:

```
% build a reading format which can accomodate the longest line
readFormat = repmat('%d',1,maxNumberOfElementPerLine) ;
```

This will return:

```
>> M
M =
1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

---

- 2) Replace the *empty* entries with a placeholder (for ex: `99`)

Define a value which you are sure you'll never have in your original data (for quick identification of empty cells), then use the `EmptyValue` parameter of the `textscan` function:

```
readFormat = repmat('%d',1,maxNumberOfElementPerLine) ;
DefaultEmptyValue = 99 ; % placeholder for "empty values"

fidcsv = fopen('differentRows.txt','r') ;
M = textscan( fidcsv , readFormat , Inf ,...
    'delimiter',',',...
    'EndOfLine','\r\n',...
    'CollectOutput',true,...
    'EmptyValue',DefaultEmptyValue) ;
```

will yield:

```
>> M
M =
1   0   1   0   1   99  99  99  99  99
1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   99
1   0   1   99  99  99  99  99  99  99
1   0   1   99  99  99  99  99  99  99
1   0   1   0   1   99  99  99  99  99
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   99
```